# xpath can't extract data from table

Tags: php, html, xpath

I write the following xpath to extract name and price from table.

```
/html/body/div[2]/div[7]/div[3]/table[1]/tbody/tr
```

http://www.iranjib.ir/showgroup/28/%D9%82%DB%8C%D9%85%D8%AA-%D8%B1%D9%88%D8%B2-%D9%85%D9%88%D8%A8%D8%A7%DB%8C%D9%84/

but it can't extract

Comment: Have you tried broadening the query to see what you can fetch? For example, does `/html/body/div[2]` get you anything? If so, how about `/html/body/div[2]/div[7]`? For what it's worth, the query is too prone to breakage anyway - it might be better to target a `table` with an `id`, perhaps? In what way can you not extract? I think we need to see some more details here.

Comment: I use fire fox plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `tbody` element in the source HTML of that page (try this yourself by opening the source document and searching for "tbody").

Unfortunately, browsers (including browser plugins, n.b.) tend to add `tbody` elements to the DOM representations even if they are not actually there.

I have no idea what you are trying to find on that page (you did not explain it clearly enough), but if you were searching for

```
//table/tbody/tr
```

and that did not return anything, the first thing you should try instead is

```
//table//tr
```

and see if it makes a difference. If it doesn't, the next thing to look out for is *namespaces*. The document that serves as your input ([**allegedly**](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.iranjib.ir%2Fshowgroup%2F28%2F%25D9%2582%25DB%258C%25D9%2585%25D8%25AA-%25D8%25B1%25D9%2588%25D8%25B2-%25D9%2585%25D9%2588%25D8%25A8%25D8%25A7%25DB%258C%25D9%2584%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0)) is XHTML, which requires elements to be in a namespace:

```
<html lang="fa" xml:lang="fa" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

Depending on the XPath engine you are using (again, we don't know), you need to cleanly register namespaces with prefixes, and prefix element names.

Comment: Now I write xpath in chrome console ....$x("//table[@class='items_table englishbold']/tbody/tr/td[@class='entry entryltr']/a/text()"); ...and get Array[546]  @Mathias Müller

Comment: @Mortzea So what? Is that different from what you expected? What are you trying to find exactly? Why did you make it look as if you are using PHP, when you are actually applying XPath expressions in the web console? (Do _not_ answer those questions in a comment, _edit_ your question to include this information.)